# Update multiple connection string in config file through AZURE realse pipeline

Tags: powershell

Hi i am using Azure pipeline for  release process . i want to change the connection strings once release time based one the server details . i just tried a power shell script for update connection string in config. it is working for a single connection string i want to update multiple connection string. what change i will do that . This is the code i am using for update single connection string

```
 $appConfig = [xml](cat \\*ip*\Test_8082_New\Service\project.ServiceHost.exe.config)
$appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add | foreach {
   $_.connectionString = "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog='Test8082_New;User Id=admin_user;Password=admin_pwd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"  
}

$appConfig.Save("\\*ip*\Test_8082_New\Service\project.ServiceHost.exe.config")
```

**I want to update multiple connection string**

Comment: What's the result if you run this powershell script locally? Can it work to update multiple connection string?

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT if i run this script i can update a single connection string file.for mutlpile string update need to update this script